# Ubuntu service auto startup not working on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, services, autostart

Hi I've created one service with name test which starts apache tomcat server and put it into /etc/init.d.
I've also written one script which makes this service as auto startup. This service (set service as auto startup) was working on my ubuntu 14.04 system, I've upgraded it to 16.04, and now i'm not able to set this service as auto starup, below is the error.

```
sudo update-rc.d openspecimen defaults
```

gives below error;
insserv: warning: script 'K01test' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'test' missing LSB tags and overrides

```
sudo update-rc.d test enable
```

gives below error;
update-rc.d: error: test Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.

I've also set default run level in service file.

## chkconfig: 2345 85 05

Not getting what issue is. Any help on this will be appreciable.

Thanks

Satish Lakhani